# UINavigationController stops pushing view

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

We use a navigation controller and a view controller to display a question to the user. Everything has been working fine but we made some UI adjustments so we can port the application to iPad, the only changes were to make the frame of the table view dynamic to be either on iphone or ipad. However now when we get to the 187 question out of 335 it doesn't push the new question anymore... it pushes a blank screen and the "viewDidLoad" method of the pushed view controller is never called, as it has been the past 187 times. We have setup break points to make sure the navigation controller and view controller are still be allocated in memory and they are.

Here is the viewDidLoad of the view controller that gets called every new push...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
_tableView = [[QuestionTableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

_tableView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
[_tableView setDataSource:self];
[_tableView setQuestionDelegate:self];
[_tableView setDelegate:self];
_tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;

[_tableView setBackgroundView:[[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease]];
_tableView.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
_tableView.delaysContentTouches = NO;

_tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
_tableView.opaque = NO;
[self.view addSubview:_tableView];

}
```

We push the the view controller by...

```
[questionsNavigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Thanks in advanced! :)

Comment: also just wanted to mention that if we run it in the simulator no problems... if we run it on either ipad or ipad2 we have the problems listed above

Comment: You have 187 view controllers on a navigation stack? I'd start there...

Comment: No its the same controller being pushed with different table data.

Comment: Then its view should be already loaded.

Comment: yes and this works 187 time... however if we make the table view smaller we can get through the entire 335....

Comment: I think you mean it's 187 different *instances* of the same view controller *class*. You quite possibly running out of (video?) memory (forgetting to release views in -viewDidUnload?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make the tableview smaller you can get through the entire set of 335 questions ? Are you creating a ViewController per question ?

You  could run the project with instruments to check for a memory leak.

Comment: its the same view controller being pushed with different table data so we reuse the view controllers view but populate it from a different object in the array.

Comment: could it be there is something special in the data for question 187 that breaks the question detail viewController ? you said you made the tableView _smaller_ , what exactly did you do ?

Comment: just set the frame of the uitableview smaller

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need all questions on the stack? How about a popViewControllerAnimated:NO before pushing the next one, also with animated:NO?

It works on the simulator because it's memory is the PC's memory. Put an NSLog into your -didReceiveMemoryWarning method to see it running out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you shouldn't use NavigationController this way. It's.. ugly.

I would do one of the following:

- "pop" ViewControllers that are 5-10 views behind (using setViewController). In other words - maintain 5-10 views behind, the others will be freed (and the result saved). Once the user decides to get back (and there are 3-4 views in the stack), reconstruct few more.
- implement the NavigationController behaviour yourself - just replace the views instead of stacking them. Once the user gets back, reload the view with the needed data.
- If you realy think that your implementation is ok - try to free as much possible memory from your view, once things get hot.